# Call specific php function through ajax don't working

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I've made a script that use an ajax request, this script basically is activated when an user press a button in the `index.php` page, like:

**Risorse.php**

```
<form  method='post'>
        Name <input type='text' name='nome' id='nome'>
        Col <input type='text' name='colore' id='colore'>
        Plan <select name='planning' id='planning'><option value='p1'>p1</option></select>
        <button type='submit' id='Aggiungi'>Register</button>
</form>
```

and this is the script:

**Index.php**

```
<script>
  $("#Aggiungi").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var nome = $("#nome").val();
    var colore = $("#colore").val();
    var planning = $("#planning").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "Class/Risorse.php",
        data: "function=test", 
        /*type: "POST",
        url: "Class/Risorse.php",
        data: 
        {  
            nome: nome,
            colore: colore,
            planning: planning
        }*/
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
        //alert("Success");

    })
        .fail(function() {
        alert('Problem');
    });
});
```

**Risorse.php**

in the class `Risorse.php` I've create the `test();` function

```
function test()
{
    echo "inserimento avvenuto con successo!";
}
```

update- code that update which function is called by ajax:

```
if(isset($_GET['function'])) 
{
    if($_GET['function'] == 'test') 
    {   
        test(); //but this function isn't called and is located in the same file
    }
}
```

but nothing happean, also ajax working good if I execute the commented code. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "but nothing happen"? You commented out the `alert(success)` part, how would you tell when the response has returned.

Comment: I mean the test function isn't called

Comment: You know that you can't call directly a php function from js... right?

Comment: yeah. Infact I want to call the function test by an ajax request, am I wrong on this?

Comment: How do you know the "test function isn't called"?, like I said earlier, you commented out the `alert(success)` part, which is supposed to let you know when your request/response have finished processing. Try to `log()` to the console the returned value, to see if it corresponds with the returned value from the server side function.

Comment: The problem is that in the network tab in the console there is function=test, see my update code so you can understand how I get the type of function required by ajax. The problem's that this code doesn't call the function test();

Comment: Are you sure about this? Just do `alert(msg);` and see what its return.

Comment: Ok seems that return page not found, but the file is located in the Class folder ..

Comment: So, you're calling the wrong page. Check the right page, and post all your `Class/Risorse.php`, because I think you might doing a lot of confusion.

Comment: No the page is correct! Because if I do test(); in the Risorse.php the function working! But I need to execute the function with an ajax request. Wait I post my Risorse.php class

Comment: You lost me at "Its calling the wrong, not found, page. But it's correct". You must clarify your question

Comment: 'Cause the url is correct but ajax doesn't find any page to this

Comment: I have no information to tell you why you don't find `Risorse.php`. Just open the console and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `data` declared twice in your `$.ajax` call. Is the php test function located in `Class/Risorse.php`? If so, your php will not automatically enter this function, but it will run the php file. Add `test();`to the top of that php file to get it to enter the funciton.

Comment: I need to execute the test function inside the ajax request. If I place test(); to the top as you said all working, but I need to call it when my ajax request is performed

Comment: `url: "Class/Risorse.php"` will get the server to run the script `Risorse.php`, but there's nothing you can do about telling ajax specifically to run `test()`. That is why you'd want to put it at the top of the php file, or omit the function and have the php script only contain `echo "inserimento avvenuto con successo!";`

Comment: Nope, I've update my question with the code that check which function was passed!

Comment: Try `data: {function: 'test'}` instead of `data: "function=test"`

Comment: Have you tried checking the developer console and seeing what the GET request looks like, if it's returning an HTTP error codes or anything?
In Chrome developer tools for example, it should have a GET request for `Class/Risorse.php?function=test` If that 404's or anything like that, you might need to modify the url slightly

Comment: Status code return Ok but in the response preview I get 404. I don't understand why because the page is correct loaded.

Comment: If it says 404 then I'm confused why it's returning Ok, those are two different hings to my understanding. Perhaps it's just a relative path issue? `url: "/Class/Risorse.php"`? I don't know the directory structure on your site

Comment: Okay I've fixed, I missing a brackets

Comment: Just curious, what brackets/where?

Comment: First were: Class/Risorse.php after => /Class/Risorse.php